# How can I make a todo or more get saved in an array property of the User that created them, in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I want to make all the newly created todos get saved an be associated with the signed in user in the MongoDB. What I have sa far is this:

**User.js**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    todos: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Todo' }]
```

});

**Todo.js**

```
const TodoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
```

});

And when I create the task I have no idea how am I supposed to make that relationship between the User and the todos:

**todoController.js**

```
exports.createTodo = function (req, res) {
    const { text, creator } = req.body;

    const newTodo = new Todo({ text, creator });

    newTodo.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: `Todo wasn't saved beacause: ${err}`
            });
        }

        res.json({
            message: `Todo created successfuly`,
        })
    });
};
```

I want to create the correct relashionship between the signed in user and the todos, more exactly I want to save the todos in the todos property of the UserSchema.

Answer (score 1):

You should store a user reference within each todo item vs the other way around.

This is a link about One to Many doc references that may help you with modeling your DB.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/